# Ruby Map Method edits the original array?

Tags: ruby, dictionary, reference, enumerate

```
def removal(arr)
    letters ="i"
    p arr  
    new_array = arr.map do |c_word|
        c_word.each_char.with_index do |char, index|
            if letters.include?(char)
                c_word[index] = "*"
            end    
        end
    end     
    p arr #the original array is getting edited? why?
    p new_array     

end

removal(["hiiiiiigh","git", "training"])
```

In this code, the original array (arr) in the map method keeps getting edited. I thought that map does not edit the original array. If I needed to edit the original, then I would use .map!

I believe it has something to do with the nested enumerator or a variable reference that I am not seeing. Instead of each_char.with_index, I used a while loop and map would still edit the original array. Why is the original array being edited?

Comment: Besides using `map` you're anyway modifying it when you do `c_word[index] = ...`. That's mutating `arr`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Think of using:

- `map` as saying *"I want to create new data based on existing data"*
- `each` as saying *"I either want to not change any data, or change existing data"*

Having this in mind, what you are doing is using `map` with array to create new array based on existing one, and then using `each` to modify characters in existing strings. This is why the strings in the original array end up modified.

To fix this use `map` twice, first to "create new array based on existing array", and then the second time to "create new string based on existing string". This way the original strings won't get modified.

```
def removal(arr)
  letters ="i"
  p arr
  new_array = arr.map do |word|
    word.chars.map do |char|
      letters.include?(char) ? '*' : char
    end.join
  end
  p arr
  p new_array
end

removal(["hiiiiiigh","git", "training"])  #=> ["hiiiiiigh", "git", "training"]
                                          #   ["hiiiiiigh", "git", "training"]
                                          #   ["h******gh", "g*t", "tra*n*ng"]
```

---

More practical solution to this problem would be something like this:

```
def censor(strings, forbidden_chars_string, censor_char = '*')
  re = Regexp.union(forbidden_chars_string.chars)
  strings.map {|str| str.gsub(re, censor_char) }
end

p ["hiiiiiigh","git", "training"]                     #=> ["hiiiiiigh", "git", "training"]
p censor(["hiiiiiigh","git", "training"], "i")        #=> ["h******gh", "g*t", "tra*n*ng"]
p censor(["hiiiiiigh","git", "training"], "gn", '_')  #=> ["hiiiiii_h", "_it", "trai_i__"]
```

Answer (score 7):

You are actually wrong in (at least) two places:

- `map` is *not* editing the original array
- in fact, the original array is not being edited *at all*

If you look closely, the array hasn't changed, *only the strings inside the array* have changed. And it is not `map` that is doing this, it is `String#[]=`, which you are calling here:

```
c_word[index] = "*"
```

So, you are calling a method that edits strings, and you should not be surprised that your strings are edited!

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because inside the map block you are doing some processing on each word of **arr** and not on each word **new_array**. If you want to copy the words of **arr** and change it in **new_array** then create a copy, change it and return the word.

Checkout these 2 codes and you will get my point

Code 1

```
def removal(arr)
    letters ="i"
    p arr
    new_array = arr.map do |c_word|
        c_word.each_char.with_index do |char, index|
            if letters.include?(char)
                c_word[index] = "*"
            end
        end
        c_word
    end
    p arr
    p new_array

end

removal(["hiiiiiigh","git", "training"])
```

Here you are changing words of **arr** and copying it to **new_array**

Code 2

```
def removal(arr)
    letters ="i"
    p arr
    new_array = arr.map do |c_word|
        n_word = c_word.dup
        n_word.each_char.with_index do |char, index|
            if letters.include?(char)
                n_word[index] = "*"
            end
        end
        n_word
    end
    p arr
    p new_array

end

removal(["hiiiiiigh","git", "training"])
```

Here you are copying words of **arr**, changing it and adding them to **new_array**

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to change the array's elements, you should not change them. Your problem is in this line:

```rb
c_word[index] = "*"
```

So just use methods that do not affect the recipient, e.g.:

```
def removal(array)
  letter = 'i'
  array.map { |word| word.gsub(letter, '*') }
end
```

Comment: This could be improved to support many letters (as replacement targets).

Comment: `regex = Regexp.new(letters.chars.map(&Regexp.method(:escape)).join('|'))`